# How do trojans/spywares eat up internet bandwidth?

Tags: windows, spyware

My internet connection has become terribly slow due to a trojan/spyware which is eating up my internet bandwidth. However, apparently there is no process consuming bandwidth according to the monitor program I am running. How is it? How do trojans and spywares manage to eat up bandwidth?

I have another question, is it possible that my internet connection is speedier or slower depending on the SO?

Comment: "apparently there is no process consuming bandwidth according to the monitor program I am running" - Which program, and how are you so sure the trojan is not able to hide its activities from said program?

Comment: asd - If you are experiencing a slow connection, a better question might be, "I'm experiencing a slow internet connection.  What are some steps I could take to determine the cause."  However, before asking that you should check to see what the answer to that question is (as I'm SURE it's been asked here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"My internet connection has become terribly slow due to a trojan/spyware which is eating up my internet bandwidth."

What process/software did you use to determine this?

"However, apparently there is no process consuming bandwidth according to the monitor program I am running."

Then how do you know this has anything to do with malware?

"How is it? How do trojans and spywares manage to eat up bandwidth?"

Software that consumes bandwidth (malware or not) uses bandwidth by sending and receiving data, exactly what your bandwidth is for.  What data is being sent, where it's going to, and what is being done on your computer locally, are all questions that when answered, will answer your question.

Your question is the subject of many good books, and as such, may not fit the Q&A format of Superuser.  There isn't enough space/time for me to go into every piece of malware and explain its use of bandwidth (if in fact the problem you are experiencing is due to malware of some sort).